# Limit providers while integrating Gigya in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, gigya

I am integrating Gigya in my iphone app. Now it provides 17 providers for access, I want to limit it to just 9 providers. How can I do that?

Has any one integrated it for iPhone? It loads a web view which displays 17 providers in a grouped table format, [see here](http://socialize.gigya.com/gs/mobile/loginui.aspx?lastLoginProvider=facebook&redirect_uri=gsapi%3A%2F%2Fnetwork_selected%2F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set Facebook and Twitter you can use following code.

```
GSDictionary *pParams5 = [[GSDictionary new] autorelease];

[pParams5 putStringValue:@"facebook,twitter" forKey:@"enabledProviders"]; 

[gsAPI showAddConnectionsUI:pParams5 delegate:self context:nil];
```

Comment: thanks, but after login i am not getting the response, Even onLoginCompleted method is not getting called.

Comment: [gsAPI showLoginUI:pParams5 delegate:self context:nil]; gives the login page, since yours giuves add connection page..

Answer (score 0):

```
 GSAPI *gsAPI // declare this  

 gsAPI = [[GSAPI alloc] initWithAPIKey:<API-KEY> viewController:self];  // i kept this in viewDidload

// add this code to have facebook and twitter on provider list

   GSDictionary *pParams5 = [[GSDictionary new] autorelease];
   [pParams5 putStringValue:@"facebook,twitter" forKey:@"enabledProviders"];  
   [gsAPI showAddConnectionsUI:pParams5 delegate:self context:nil];


//this method called when login fails
  -(void)gsLoginUIDidFail:(int)errorCode errorMessage:(NSString*)errorMessage context:(id)context{ }

// this method called on successful login
  - (void)  gsLoginUIDidLogin:(NSString*)provider user:(GSDictionary*)user context:(id)context {}
```

Check whether you have valid API